# Why does the SymPy diophantine module occasionally return a solution for an expression in some symbols, but not for the same expression in others?

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving, diophantine

Having imported the following:

```
from sympy.solvers.diophantine.diophantine import diop_ternary_quadratic
from sympy.abc import x,y,z,d,h,c
```

Running the code `diop_ternary_quadratic(-7938*x**2+14436*x*y-98*y**2-z**2)` returns `(761, 441, 15120)`, however running `diop_ternary_quadratic(-7938*d**2+14436*d*h-98*h**2-c**2)`, which is equivilent to the first line, the only difference being the symbols used, returns `(None,None,None)`. Why does this happen? Furthermore how would one remedy this?

I've found that this issue only happens for some expressions, for example `diop_ternary_quadratic(d**2+h**2-c**2)` spits out `(1,0,1)` as expected.

This problem is not on my end as running it in SymPy's online shell produses the same results.

A possible fix could be exchanging `d,h,c` for `x,y,z`, however that would make my code harder to parse by humans, and introduce other "icky" problems, as well as not assuage my question.

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: The docs could be clearer about this but the function you are using is not intended for end users: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html#user-functions

Comment: I suspect there is a bug at play. If you try to run the c,d,h form first in a new SymPy session, do you get an answer? (I am getting a recursion error when I try to solve this equation whether I use the x,y,z or c,d,h form.)

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thank you, I'll try useing the user-facing `diophantine` function and see if that works. (Although I'd still like to know why my problem arises, if not for anything but for knowledge's sake.)

Comment: @smichr I worried as much. For me, the problem still arises whether I run the cdh form first, or even alone, not even importing the variables xyz.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, I just tried your suggestion, and unfortunately, the discrepancy still persists.